# d3.js mouseover not working with multi line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, linechart

i've been trying to create an interactive multi line d3 chart.it's very simple right now, and this is what it looks like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27lPU.png)

the vertical line will show the values at each x point. this mouseover works. but the mouseover/mouseout I want is to select the line I am on, and blur the rest.
I basically want something like this: http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518

But nothing I do really works..
Here's the code

```
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 50},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 670 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var priceline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); })


// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    // if (error) return console.error(error);

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());
        d.price = +d.price;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; })]);

    // Nest the entries by symbol
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.symbol;}) //change to name
        .entries(data)


    var color = d3.scale.category10();


    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log("d", d);
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .attr("d", priceline(d.values))
            // .on("mouseover", mouseover) this doesn't work! I am thinking it's because I am nesting + using a for loop for each line, but I have to do this since my dataset is quite big and idk how many lines I will be needing
            // .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    });


    function mouseover(d) {
      console.log("no");
      var me = this;
      //d3.select(d.line).classed("line--hover", true);
      d3.selectAll(".line").classed("line--hover", function() {
        return (this === me);
      }).classed("line--fade", function() {
        return (this !== me);
      });
    }

    function mouseout(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .classed("line--hover", false)
        .classed("line--fade", false);
    }

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);


    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Price in USD");

    var dataL = 0;
    var offset = 100;

    var legend = d3.select('svg')
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(color.domain())
      .enter()
      .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend')
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
             if (i === 0) {
                dataL = d.length + offset
                return "translate(0,0)"
            } else {
             var newdataL = dataL
             dataL +=  d.length + offset
             return "translate(" + (newdataL) + ",0)"
            }
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr("x", 68)
      .attr("y", 650)
      .text(function (d, i) {
            return d
        })
      .attr("class", "textselected")
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
            .style("font-size", 15)

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(dataNest)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");


    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        // console.log("bye");
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");

      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

            var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

            while (true){
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + 1050 + "," + 620 +")";
          });
    });
});
```

The data looks something like this:

```
symbol,date,price
MSFT,Jan 2000,39.81
MSFT,Feb 2000,36.35
MSFT,Mar 2000,43.22
MSFT,Apr 2000,28.37
MSFT,May 2000,25.45
MSFT,Jun 2000,32.54
MSFT,Jul 2000,28.4
MSFT,Aug 2000,28.4
MSFT,Sep 2000,24.53
MSFT,Oct 2000,28.02
MSFT,Nov 2000,23.34
MSFT,Dec 2000,17.65
MSFT,Jan 2001,24.84
MSFT,Feb 2001,24
MSFT,Mar 2001,22.25
MSFT,Apr 2001,27.56
```

symbol represents companies, which I might have around 100 of. (this is just sample data)

the css is very simple

```
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line--fade {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.line--hover {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

I also tried using tipsy.js but I'm not sure how to integrate it properly into my code.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you post your semi-working code on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?
That way we can see the issue and fiddle with it (see what I did there?) till it works. Also we could have a look at your HTML

Comment: @ghosh I am not really familiar with jsfiddle, but this is the closest I can get. Not actually sure how to use csv data :( https://jsfiddle.net/c79fj9qg/#&togetherjs=lrbRfO2gR0 I actually solved the previous problem, but now cannot zoom in and out for some reason :'( thanks a ton for the help really!!

Comment: the error I am getting is `Uncaught TypeError: d3.zoom is not a function`

Comment: try  d3.behavior.zoom()
check the link that you posted yourself to see how --> http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518

Comment: yah, unfortunately, i tried that too. i guess the problem is that function zoomed() has to be outside the d3.csv and when I try to do `function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  svg.selectAll(".line")
      .attr("class","line")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        console.log("d", d);
        return priceline(d.price)});
}` d.price cannot be called, so the lines do not move along with the zoom. the axis change but the lines are the same